# Regardless of what currency I send into Sitecore CDP, it is being converted to another currency. How is the currency setup in CDP?

Tags: personalization, cdp, sitecore-personalize

I am sending in **ADD** stream events into `Sitecore CDP` or `Sitecore Personalize` with the currency set to **EUR** yet the currency is **USD** in the guest profile. How can I set the currency to **EUR**? How is the currency being converted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In “`System Settings`” under “`Company Information`” the configuration for the `Sitecore CDP` and `Sitecore Personalize` tenant is setup, this includes the base currency. The base currency determines what currency all orders will be converted into. Both the original currency and base currency are stored.

Both the base currency and the original currency are stored in the **CDP** and can be used for Personalization. The base currency is the currency displayed on guest profiles dashboards.

For example, if an organization's headquarters are in the USA then their base currency is likely to be **USD**. If a customer completes an order on the UK website in **GDP**, then this will be converted into the base currency **USD** in `Sitecore CDP`.

When the original currency is converted into the base currency the FX rates are based on https://openexchangerates.org/